# Dividing graph into subgraphs with even edges

Tags: graph

-4

I am trying to solve this problem

Given an undirected graph with N vertices and M edges, how can I divide the graph into the minimum number of subgraphs such that all the subgraphs will contain an even number of edges

NOTE: In all subgraphs edges not connecting two vertices in that subgraph are not counted

N and M are both guaranteed to be less than 100,001.

When the number of edges is positive, then we can put them all in one subgraph.

Can you suggest any algorithm I can use or look up, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.codechef.com/OCT19A/problems/EVEDG
It's a problem from an ongoing contest.